# Usage of 'the city of [Name the city]' or just '[Name the city]'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, usage

​I'm trying to translate in English the part of address related to the name of the city. Which variant is correct?

> ```
> 1 - the city of Samara
> 2 - Samara
> ```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context for this phrase? What does the rest of the address look like, translated?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the purpose of this translation? Is it a story, or a letter/correspondence? Is the name of the city "City of Samara" or just "Samara"? There are many options and "which variant is correct" can depend all of these factors.

Comment: Most cities just use the city name. There are cases which need to be specified because of ambiguity. For example "London" vs. "the City of London"

Comment: @Max I think OP already said that is a part of an address. So, I think, Samara is correct. e.g., 12, Av. XX, Samara, Russia.

Comment: @Max, I'm just trying to express my personal address in a reference letter in proper international address format.

Comment: For a proper international address, you just need the name- Samara.

Answer (score 1):

Just write Samara, for postal addresses.

Unless the official name of your city is actually "City of Samara" - e.g. in the US you have "Oklahoma City" which is the actual full name of the city.

Postal addresses have expected data in specific slots, e.g. for US postal addresses:

> [Name]
>
> [Address Number] [Street Name] [Street Abbreviation]
>
> [City] [State] [ZIP Code]

So it is usually known you mean a city already by where you put it in the address.